# How to call ReactDOM.render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I use webpack for bundling JS with the entry point as `main.tsx`.

File `main.tsx` is shown below. The `<div>` with `myId` is present only in my home page where the React component is getting rendered correctly. However in all other pages, I am getting a React error in console saying element with `myId` cannot be found, which is true. Now I am using an `if` condition to check for the presence of `myId` and then calling `ReactDOM.render` to make sure  that render is attempted only on my home page (shown below).. The error doesn't show up in other pages now. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

```
let rootId = document.getElementById('myId');
if(rootId) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Hello compiler="TypeScript" framework="React" />,
        document.getElementById("myId")
    );

}
```

Comment: All you application should be contained in one container and you should render that component into the DOM and not each and every component separately

Comment: Mine is not a single page app. I am only rendering the top most component of every page.

Comment: You should try to use a router, so you don't have interaction with the DOM. Everything should be managed through react, and not rely on the DOM which can be altered.

Comment: Using Webpack can create [multiple entry points](https://webpack.github.io/docs/multiple-entry-points.html) for each page so that you only render the single component for each page.